# Rails 5 with mongoid .changed is always empty on update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, activerecord, mongoid, ruby-on-rails-5

In my controller, I have the *_params to permit attributes.  No matter what, even when things are definitely changed, .changed is always blank.  Is there a new Rails 5 way to detect changed attributes?

```
# case_params is the basic rails controller permission method
if @case.update(case_params)
      puts @case.changed.count # this is is always 0
      ...
```

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong? I need to know what's changed so I can selectively do some other work in a thread but only for changed attributes.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Mongoid uses [`Mongoid::Changeable`](https://github.com/mongodb/mongoid/blob/7847b38103de798e567fec24d998df8e42971158/lib/mongoid/changeable.rb) instead of [`ActiveModel::Dirty`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Dirty.html). So the behavior is not strongly coupled to rails and may differ from ActiveRecord.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `@cases.previous_changes` which gives all the changes to the document in the form of a hash. The hash also consitis of `updated_at` attribute. You can do -1 to the above count to get all the changed attributes count excluding updated_at.

You can get the count by `@cases.previous_changes.keys.count - 1`

We need to subtract -1 for removing updated_at attribute changes.

If you want to detect changes in the assosiation you can use try using `children_changed?` for it.

Comment: this appears to not work for embeds_many objects, it's always 0, even if you change an embedded object and can see the change work, previous_changes and changes are always empty.